# Not able to handle multiple c files and header files during compilation

Tags: c

I read that the C file containing the function definition should be of the same name as the header file. So, i created two files: functions.h, functions.c & lastly the main.c file which calls the functions which are defined inside of the functions.c file.

```
//functions.h file

void check();
```

I have declared `check` function in the header file

```
//functions.c file 

#include <stdio.h> 
#include "functions.h"

int main(void){
void check(){
printf("\nThis is a Test\n"); 
}
return 0; 
}
```

This file contains all the function definition. But one thing i want to clear out is, I saw some another question on stackoverflow of basically the same type but in function file he had just included the header files and function definitions, without main(). Shouldn't that .c file throw an error?

```
//main.c file
#include "function.h"
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
check(); 
return 0; 
}
```

when i open terminal and type the command to compile the code:

```
 clang main.c
```

I get an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_check", referenced from:
     _main in heap-22db64.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

May be i haven't compiled functions.c file that's the reason i see this. I am just compiling main.c. I am not sure about this linking error. If i have 35 .c files. Compiling all of them via commandline would be harder task? What should be my approch to deal with these big projects. Having multiple C & header files?

Comment: Yes, you have to compile every file that has functions used in the main program and link them. There can be only one definition of each function, including `main`, which should only be defined in one file. I see no definition of `check()` at all in what you've shown us here.

Comment: Not sure if it is a build tool you're after, but, if you are, what about make? [Here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)'s a good link with some starting points on how to use it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker i have edited the question i typed it wrong on the site. My code in pc was right. Now i have edited the code exactly as in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the typical scenario:

```
// functions.c
void check(void) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Note: just the definition of check, and nothing else. Then a header:

```
// functions.h
extern void check(void);
```

Just a declaration. Then the main file:

```
// main.c
#include "functions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    check();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When definitions are provided in another file, you have to specify that like so using the `extern` keyword:

`functions.h`:

```
extern void check();
```

`functions.c`:

```
void check()
{
    printf("\nThis is a Test\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer that's functions.h not functions.c in main.c . I didn't noticed that while re-typing the code here on website. Sorry

Comment: Next time i'll copy paste code from compiler to site..sry again